# Notepad++ Delete History

Tags: notepad++

My notepad++ starts up really slow and I suspect this is because I have a huge history of files opened. 99.9% of these I don't need anymore. How do I delete the history and keep it from saving opened files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Open file session.xml in C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++ or %APPDATA%\Notepad++
2. Delete its contents and save it
3. Run Notepad++ , session.xml will get new content automatically

Comment: For me I had to delete the file (I physically removed from the directory) from the  C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++\backups folder that solved the issue.